# How to Send Variable from php page to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm a beginner of PHP and want to send Variable in this case Number of views how can i do it if i have the variable in js code

```css
.views{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <h4>23"</h4>
  <p class="moments">1</p>

  <p><button type="button" onclick="clickver2()" id= ez1>Add to Cart</button></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let clicks = 0;
    function clickver2() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "Views:" + clicks;
    };
  </script>
  <p class="views" id="clicks"></p>
```

```php
function openconn(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "ez";
    $views;


    $conn = new mysqli($servername , $username , $password , $db) or die("Connection Failed".$conn ->error);

    return $conn;
}

function closeconn($conn){
    $conn ->close();
}
```

How i can transfer Clicks to Variable in PHP

Comment: Learn about AJAX.

Comment: Changed snippet from HTML to PHP and also removed extra tags from HTML snippet

Answer (score 0):

A simple, tried, and true method would be to use an HTML Form. Action can be set to the page you wish to resolve the variables, form fields have your data, and submit... submits the form.

Comment: I don't understanding what u mean can you give an example?

Comment: I realize that I MAY have misread your OP. You said you want to send the variable, but checking over your code it looks like you just want to check it on the same page.. are you trying to pass this variable to a new page or simply increase the value on the current page?

One reason for my confusion is that PHP is a server-side language whereas Javascript runs in the browser.